# NodeJS: Assigning to variable data retrieved asynchronously in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a simple Firebase backend for a Dialogflow chatbot. The app interacts with a few databases and retrieves data from them. My code looked something like this:

```
function_A (assistant) {
  let key_a = assistant.getArgument(KEY_A_NAME); 
  database_a.child(key_a).once("value", snap => {
        if (snap.val() == null) {
          //not reachable
           assistant.tell('Error Message');
                }
        else {
          let result = snap.val()[PROPERTY_NAME]
          <do_something_with result>
        }
  });
```

}

```
function_B (assistant) {
      let key_B = assistant.getArgument(KEY_B_NAME); 
      database_B.child(key_B).once("value", snap => {
            if (snap.val() == null) {
              //not reachable
               assistant.tell("ErrorMessage);
                    }
            else {
              let result = snap.val()[PROPERTY_NAME]
              <do something else with result>
            }
      });   
}
```

I now want to refactor the code and reuse database retrieval. I tried to do something like this:

```
function function_A(assistant) {
        let key_a = assistant.getArgument(KEY_A_NAME); 
        const property = retrieve_from_database(database_a, key_a, PROPERTY_A_NAME);

        if (property == null) {
            //not reachable
            assistant.tell('Error Message');
        }
        else {
            <do something with property>
        }
    }

function retrieve_from_database(db, key, entry_name) {
        const ref = db.child(key);

        return ref.once("value").then(function(snap) {
            if (snap.val() == null) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return snap.val()[entry_name];
            }
        });
    }
```

However, the retrieve_from_database function returns a Promise object, and as much as I read about Promises, I still don't understand how to retrieve the needed information from it and store it into a variable. It seems there is something fundamental I fail to understand here. I'm very new to NodeJS and Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you're looking to do:

```
function function_A(assistant) {
    let key_a = assistant.getArgument(KEY_A_NAME); 
    retrieve_from_database(database_a, key_a, PROPERTY_A_NAME).then(function(property) {
      if (property == null) {
        assistant.tell('Error Message');
      }
      else {
        <do something with property>
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! So simple, but I just couldn't grasp it. Thank you.